# Small animation when link is clicked with jquery or pure css

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have seen a small animation on a website, I want to know how it is done.

It is the website bellow. If you look at the menu at the top, when the links are clicked, they move a little and back again. Can I do this with jquery, or can it be done with pure css also.

If it is done by jquery, do you have the code for me also. Thanks

*link removed*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using CSS:

```
a:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
```

You can learn more here: http://css-tricks.com/5420-one-pixel-shift-buttons/

Comment: Personally i just cant understand why to use `position` and `top`. I would use `margin` or especially `padding` in this case cause its a link. You can do the same thing even with bigger shifts as long as you keep the padding in check. `padding: 10px;` becomes something like `padding: 14px 10px 6px 10px;` that way the text shifts inside the link area and you dont have to worry about the link disappearing on `:hover` for example. Also `line-height` is something to think about.

Answer (score 1):

There is no animation, I think, just changing position.
For example:

```
.menuItem:active {
    margin-top: 1px; /* or padding-top or just top */
    position: relative;
}
```